# Showing column names

Tags: php, mysql, database, class, mysqli

This class is for managing a database through mysqli. I'm stuck on the prepared statement to show all the column names of a given table.

```
class databaseManager {
    function showTable ($tableName, $mysqli) {
        $stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("SHOW COLUMNS FROM ?");
        $stmt -> bind_param('s', $tableName);
        $stmt -> execute();

        while ($stmt -> fetch) {
            $Field;
        }

        $stmt -> free_result();
    }
}
```

I get the error "Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object", but $mysqli connection exists so I suppose the mysqli -> prepare is wrong.

EDIT: clearly I passed $mysqli

```
$databaseManager = new databaseManager();
$databaseManager -> showTable("blog", $mysqli);
```

Comment: Your code is correct. Check your $mysqli variable. You could test the prepare result like this : $stmt = $db->prepare("SHOW COLUMNS FROM ?") or die($db->error());

Comment: I don't think it's so correct because they are telling me that I cannot parametrize table names in mysqli!

Comment: What resource did you use to learn OOP in PHP? I'm asking because I'm wondering about `$var -> foo` (the spaces).

Comment: I am totally self-taught by using online documentations. Actually I have the whole code working but with normal functions and with mysql_* which now is deprecated and unsecure. Are those spaces an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you aren't doing any error handling. 
Always check results of all database interactions.

For example,

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SHOW COLUMNS FROM ?");
if (!$stmt) {
    throw new Exception($mysqli->error);
}
```

so, you will get an error message from database.

Next, you can't bind identifier via prepared statement.
So, you have to either whitelist it of format it properly, according to [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html)

By the way, I see not much point in such a function. I am using console for this purpose and other people usually see their database structure via PHPMyAdmin

Also, using bare API is not the best choice. By using some abstraction layer you can make your code in one line:

```
function showTable ($tableName) {
    return $this->db->getCol("SHOW COLUMNS FROM ?n", $tableName);
}
```

You don't need this query to show table contents though, as column names always already present in a resultset. So, just request your data first and then extract column names from it

by using such a library mentioned above, it would be like this

```
$data  = $this->db->getAll("SELECT * FROM ?n", $tableName);
$names = array_keys($data[0]);
```

But still PHPMyAdmin is WAY better at it, give it a try

If you need some sort of online table editor, it is *seldom* works such straight way. There are always some issues which require pre- or post-processing of data. And for whatever complex data structure you always end up with dedicated code. To show nice column titles for example.
But for a few plain string values it would work.

Comment: The point of the function is not only to show column names, but the WHOLE table in the output (I just started). I would like to pass this function every table I want and then print all of it's contents, just by passing the table name. Am I on the wrong way?

Comment: But how can PHPMyAdmin help me when I want to create a sort of admin panel? Let's say I want to show all the posts in my blog table, update them, remove rows and so on.. I need this function

Comment: Do you have any suggestions to achieve this, then?

Answer (score 0):

By design, table names and column names cannot be parameterized. But you can still concatenate it on the string and wrapping it with backquotes as the first level of defense against sql injection.

```
    $stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("SHOW COLUMNS FROM `" . $tableName . "`");
    $stmt -> execute();
```

Comment: To the downvoter, "*I'd love to hear what is not helpful or wrong about my answer, to deserve a downvote. That way I can improve my answer. Thanks*"

Comment: Will I be safe even this way? Just for curiosity, why can't they be parametrized?

Comment: Never use strings straight in your query, this can lead to sql injections and is one of the main reasons mysql got deprecated and mysqli became the new standard. This particular solution can be safe if $tableName is never user submitted, otherwise do not use this. But really, you shouldn't anyway.